# Using LINQ, how to convert a IList<IList<object>> to IList<object>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to convert a `IList<IList<object>>` to `IList<object>`, I mean to have a unique and one list where contains all the element (object) of the first one.

```
    public IList<IList<Page>> PMTs
    {
        get
        {
            var pmts = Processes.Select(x => x.PageMapTable)
                                .ToList();
            return pmts;
        }
    }

    public IList<Page> BlockMapTable
    {
        get
        {
            // Incomplete
            var btm = PMTs.Select(x => x.?? ..
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to flatMap/flatten the `list<list<Page>>`, you can do that with selectMany method, like so:

```
public IList<Page> BlockMapTable
{
    get
    {
        var btm = PMTs.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
    }
}
```

if you want to read more about it, here is a [great blog post about selectMany extension method](http://www.codethinked.com/the-linq-selectmany-operator)

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<Page> BlockMapTable
    {
        get
        {
            return PMTs.SelectMany(p => p).ToList();
        }
    }
```